# Renaming index values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would need to change the name of my indices:

```
Country                                             Date     (other columns)
/link1/subpath2/Text by Poe/
/link1/subpath2/Text by Wilde/
/link1/subpath2/Text by Whitman/
```

Country and Date are my indices. I would like to extract the words Poe, Wilde and Whitman from index column Country in order to have

```
Country                                             Date     (other columns)
Poe
Wilde
Whitman
```

Currently I am doing it one by one:

```
df=df.rename(index={'/link1/subpath2/Text by Poe/': 'Poe'})
df=df.rename(index={'/link1/subpath2/Text by Wilde/': 'Wilde'})
df=df.rename(index={'/link1/subpath2/Text by Whitman/': 'Whitman'})
```

It works, but since I have hundreds of datasets, as you can imagine is not doable

Comment: you want to extract always the last word?

Comment: Yes, before the last /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a pattern to catch the last word with `(\w*)`, delimited by a white space `\s` before and after the character `/` at the end of the line `$`. Because it is an index, you need to rebuild the [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html).

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index.get_level_values(0)
                                              .str.extract('\s(\w*)\/$')[0], 
                                      df.index.get_level_values(1)], 
                                     names=['Country', 'Dates'])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str.replace`:

```
 df['Country'] = df['Country'].str.replace(r'/link1/subpath2/Text by ', '') 
 df['Country'] = df['Country'].str.replace(r'/', '')
```

If 'Country' is an `Index` you can do as follows:

```
df = df.set_index('Country')
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'/link1/subpath2/Text by ', '')
```

If it's a `MultiIndex` you can use `.reset_index`:

```
df = df.reset_index()  
df['Country'] = df['Country'].str.replace(r'/link1/subpath2/Text by ', '')
```

Comment: you can probably do both at the same time with `|` between both patterns, like `r'/link1/subpath2/Text by |/'`

Comment: I have a problem to apply this line of code, probably because Country is an index column

Comment: KeyError: Country

Comment: Okay, i see. You can try this: df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'/link1/subpath2/Text by ', ''). Otherwise you could reset the index: df = df.reset_index() and then do the indexing as you have it df['Country'].

Comment: Now I am getting this error: `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with Index, not MultiIndex` (I think because also date is an index column)

Comment: Ok since it's MultiIndex i think you need to reset the index to reach your goal: df = df.reset_index() and then --> df['Country'] = df['Country'].str.replace(r'/link1/subpath2/Text by ', '')

Answer (score 2):

You can always use regex pattern if things get more complicated:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['foo', 'bar', 'z'], index=['/link1/subpath2/Text by Poe/',
                                               '/link1/subpath2/Text by Wilde/', 
                                               '/link1/subpath2/Text by Whitman/'])

name_pattern = re.compile(r'by (\w+)/')
df.index = [name_att.findall(idx)[0] for idx in df.index]
df
```

[image]

where name_pattern will capture all groups between *'by '* and *'/'*

Comment: ```df.index = [name_pattern.findall(idx)[0] for idx in df.index]```

Comment: Thank you Victor. Unfortunately it is still not working :( `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`